# How to avoid Object is possibly null for Typescript value that can be null or undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I allow nulls/undefined in this reference if the value can actually be null or undefined. My if statement doesn't seem to capture it.

I get error TS2531. Object is possibly 'null'. Please help.

```
type formatterType = string | number | undefined | null;

export const formatPercent = (value: formatterType, multiplier = 1): string => {
  const val = numeral(value);
  if (value !== null || value !== undefined) {
  if (val.value()) {
    return `${val.value() * multiplier}%`;
  }
}
  return '0%';
};
```

Comment: Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ8v1w), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  This will allow those who want to help you to immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  And it will make it so that any answer you get is testable against a well-defined use case.

Answer (score 0):

`val` is an instance of the `Numeral` class. The method `value()` on this class has return type `number | null`. Therefore, it is illegal to multiply the return value without checking for null. You cannot guard against this by calling `val.value()` in the if statement, as typescript has no way of knowing whether the two calls will return the same value. You must use a variable for storing the result:

```
let v = val.value()
if (v) {
  return `${v * multiplier}%`;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as expected if `v = 0` though.